# Angular version showing different version

Tags: asp.net, angular, npm, visual-studio-2017

I've created an ASP.Net Angular 4 project from the template and then updated Angular to the latest version by doing the following:

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates
ncu -u
```

I then re-opened my project and the `packages.json` file shows the correct versions. However, when I expand `Dependecies->npm` I see that the version is still 4.2.5.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following:

1. Delete the `node_modules` folder
2. Run `npm install`

Works now.